# Error decoding signature in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I use JWT in my API. But I can't authenticate with JWT. What is the problem I couldn't find. Thanks for your helps.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def UserLogin(request):
    try:
        username = request.POST.get('username', None)
        password = request.POST.get('password', None)
        account = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    except (User.DoesNotExist, User.PasswordDoesNotMatch):
            return Response({'message': 'Wrong credentials'}, status=400)
    if account is not None:
        if account.is_active:
            login(request, account)
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                    user_type = '0'
            elif request.user.is_instructor():
                    user_type = '1'
            elif request.user.is_student():
                    user_type = '2'
            else:
                    user_type = '3'

            payload = {
                    'user_type': user_type,
                    'username': username,
                    'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=JWT_EXP_DELTA_SECONDS)
                }
            jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, JWT_SECRET, JWT_ALGORITHM)
            return Response({'token': jwt_token.decode('utf-8')})
```

Payload data returns

```
{
  "user_type": "0",
  "username": "bus",
  "exp": 1475480008
}
```

It is enough for me. But when I request Other API url, It returns

```
{
  "detail": "Error decoding signature."
}
```

Comment: If you haven't done it yet and as a quick troubleshooting step I would grab the JWT being generated and manually validate it at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). Depending on the outcome, you may get some more information about the source of the issue.

Comment: I got it. What should I use for get some information? For example jwt_payload_handler.  And exactly I don't know that how to hide specific information in token like password. Shall you give an example please? Thank you. @JoãoAngelo

Comment: In almost all situations, you should not be storing a password in a token, so if it's not there you don't need to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I can suggest to you is not to implement the JWT logic by yourself. Please use the package `dj_rest_auth` or if you only need the JWT logic, use `SimpleJWT`. The dj_rest_auth package provides you with full-featured functionalities for authentication and authorization. It also uses SimpleJWT by default as its backend for JWT implementation and functionalities.

Links:

https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/